# select box auto selected as a default

Tags: jquery, html

I want when adding a new item with jquery

```
$("#dve option").dblclick(function() {
$(this).clone().appendTo("#edno");
});
```

The item to be added, as selected to the select box, how to do that ?

Comment: @gameboyzgame; see my updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [`jQuery.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)  in **jQuery v1.6**

```
$(this).clone().appendTo("#edno").prop('selected',true)
```

see also the performance between `attr()` and `prop()` [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/)

Comment: It is giving an error with the prop that says there is no method prop

Comment: prop method is introduces in `jQuery v1.6;` sorry to forget mention it

Answer (score 1):

you can use that..

```
$(this).clone().appendTo("#edno").attr('selected',true);
```

hope its work